# Why does expressions in Wit.ai Inbox keep coming back?

Tags: sentiment-analysis, wit.ai

I've extracted some tweets and input it on Wit.ai for a sentiment analysis. Then i'm validating one by one.
[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9odi.jpg)

The problem is after i validate them, they disappear normally as Wit understood what to do. Then it appears again. Is it like a "didn't work, please try again"?

I don't know what to do. Do i just keep validating until it stops showing again?

Comment: add more details, cant understand what's wrong with that attribute

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Hope its clearer

Comment: I don't know what to do. Do i just keep validating until it stops showing again?

Answer (score 0):

I think the NLP module has not been retrained yet, so it keeps showing these questions (even if they have been already validated) because the engine still don't understand them.

You can click in the circle next to your bot name to know when the next training is scheduled (normally in a few seconds after adding a new sentence).